# VLC is able to connect rtsp, but openCV and ffmpeg

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc, rtsp

I am trying to access live video stream via OpenCV. Firstly, I am typing the rtsp url in VLC and I can see the video without any problem

However, when I put the same rtsp url into my python code and ffmpeg, it is not able to catch any information.

The python code is very easy as following and I always got "error" print message at very first time.

```
import cv2

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://XX.XX.XX.XX/mystream')
while True:
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("test", frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
    else:
        print("error")
        break
```

and also, the ffmpeg part I just simply type following command to test is there any information I can access or not. But it is still not working.

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://XX.XX.XX.XX/mystream
```

The codec I got from the VLC as the picture below:

[image]

Does anyone have the same problem with me? and how to figure it out?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you exactly write the same url which you used in vlc?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk absolutely

Comment: Did you finally solve this issue? I'm facing the exactly same problem.